# How to get a difference year, month, day between two dates in android App

Tags: android, android-calendar, nsdatecomponents

I am developing an android App.

I would like to know how to calculate exact number of "years, months and days" between two dates.

e.g.
1. "2014.1.3" to "2015.1.4"
        →Answer: "1 year and 1 day"

2. "2013.1.3" to "2014.4.2"
       →Answer: "1 year and 2 months and 30 days"

I think iPhone app has this class "NSDateComponent(NSYearCalendarUnit,NSMonthCalendarUnit,NSDayCalendarUnit)", but it seems not for the Android.

Is there any effective way in android?

Comment: There is the Java calender API. See this: http://www.mkyong.com/java/java-date-and-calendar-examples/ and this: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Calendar.html

Comment: Thank you for your reply. I know calendar API, but I have no idea about how to solve the above question with the API. Could you tell me sample codes?

Comment: I could. But it would be so much easier for both of us if you used google and found the hundreds of thousands of examples already out there.

Comment: I think it is not so easy. For example, must take leap year into account. Calculating only difference of days is easy, but calculating the difference with a format of "years and months and days" is tiresome. I would like to find an effective easy way.

Answer (score 1):

If I were you I would use subtrings to split each year, month and day into strings using the "."s as guides

```
year1String = date.substring(0,4);
month1String = date.substring(5,6);
day1String = date.substring(7,8);

year2String = date.substring(0,4);
month2String = date.substring(5,6);
day2String = date.substring(7,8);
```

and then convert those strings into integers (say year1, year2, month1, month2, day1 and day2).
Then I would just do basic subtraction:

```
int years = year2 - year1;
int months = month2 - month1;
int days = day2 - day1;
String answer = Integer.toString(years) + "." + Integer.toString(months) + "." + Integer.toString(days);
```